# How to get code coverage with logic based on screen flow variables?

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, visual-workflow, code-coverage

I am trying to get code coverage to deploy a class that depends on variables set in a screen flow.

I've read various articles saying it's not possible to get coverage for screen flows. Is this accurate in the context of apex classes that reference screen flows? What about apex classes that have logic based on screen flow variables such as `if (myFlow1.getVariableValue('variableInFlow') == 'thisValue')`? I might be able to work something out with `Test.isRunningTest()`, but I'm assuming there is a better way?

How would I get coverage in the below example?

```
public without sharing class ContainerClass 
{
    //Flow Names
    public Flow.Interview.myFlow1 myFlow1{get;set;} 
    public Flow.Interview.myFlow2 myFlow2 {get;set;} 

    public string flowName {get;set;}

    public ContainerClass()
    {

        flowName = '';

    }

    public void receiveFlowName(){ 
    //Receiving and setting flowName variable from actionFunction assignTo
    }

    public pageReference getfinishNavigation(){
        PageReference pageRef;
        pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/flowPage');
        String value1 = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('value1');
        String value2 = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('value2');
        pageRef.getParameters().put('value1',  value1 );
        pageRef.getParameters().put('value2',  value2 );

        system.debug('flowName: ' + flowName);

        switch on flowName {
            when 'myFlow1' {
                if(myFlow1 != null) { 
                    switch on String.valueOf(myFlow1.getVariableValue('finishLocation')) {
                        when 'thisPage' {
                            pageRef = new pageReference('/apex/thisPage');
                            pageRef.getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(myFlow1.getVariableValue('caseId')));
                            pageRef.setRedirect(true);
                            pageRef.getParameters().put('isFlowFinished', 'true');
                            return pageRef;
                        }
                        when 'thatPage' {
                            ...
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Could you update your processing to leverage InvocableMethods and have these receive any necessary values through parameters? That way you can decouple the code from the flows and apply standard unit testing approaches...

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, so a user enters an input in a screen flow, I pass that input into an InvocableMethod which would return a value to that same flow? Where would I pass this return value back to so that the testing approach would change?

Comment: If you need to return a value from the invocable method you can. The return value can be placed into a flow variable or similar as needed. If you don't need a return value, that's also fine. Take a look at how this all works in the [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not following how this addresses my question. I am familiar with invocable methods. How do you suggest I use an invocable method to get around the fact that have I logic in an apex class based on the flow variable? Whether this is an apex class or passed to an invocable method, how would I mock or test myFlow1.getVariableValue('finishLocation')?

Comment: My point is, use InvocableMethod to decouple your code; accept the value of finishLocation as an input to the method so the code no longer needs you to mock this value out. I am suggesting a refactoring that removes all use of the Flow.Interview.X stuff so you don't have this mocking worry. To test the Apex you just directly call the InvocableMethod from your unit test code.